# Python 3 Error: ExternalError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on line 48 in main.py

Tags: python-3.x

I'm testing my Python Code for a Restaurant App, when testing it out, I get the following Error: ExternalError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on line 48 in main.py

You can check the program here:

https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/8afa421565

Does anyone know how to correct it? Thank you

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code and the complete error traceback in your question itself. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace please?